# How to store all data in database using session and retrieve it to use as ID in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, session

I want to store all the ID into session let's just say i have 2 data in my row which is ID 1 and 2
now I want to store that two ID so that I can call it later.

```
if ($Reservation_Result->num_rows > 0) 
    {
        while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryReservation))
         {
         $RID = $row['Reservation_ID'];
         } 
    }
 echo $RID; // and this will show the ID 1 and 2
```

now how can i store it in session like 
`$ID1 = $_SESSION['Reservation_ID']` and
`$ID2 = $_SESSION['Reservation_ID']`
so that I can call `$ID1` and `$ID2` to run some queries later?

Comment: use to store `Reservation_id` as array

Comment: SeeJay check my answer. I hope it will help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.Add `session_start();` on top of the code just after starting`<?php` so that you can use `SESSION` on the page.

2.Now change code like below:-

```
if ($Reservation_Result->num_rows > 0) 
{
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($queryReservation))
     {
      $_SESSION['reservation_ids'][]= $row['Reservation_ID'];
     } 
}
print_r($_SESSION['reservation_ids']);//to check that it's created and have values in it.
```

3.To use it on other pages also you need to have `session_start();` on those page too (on top). And remember it's an array so treat it like an array not an string variable.

4.To get values from the array:-

```
foreach($_SESSION['reservation_ids'] as $value){
 echo "ID : $value \n";
}
```

Comment: Thank you. but now I am having trouble with my loop. it seems to show only 1 data when there's 2 but maybe the problem is in my queries.

Comment: It's working perfectly fine now the problem is my queries. Thank you again! I add an extra code to make it work the way i wan't.

Comment: you can use `foreach()` instead of creating multiple variables.

Comment: I don't know how that works but yeah gonna try to search it. Im new to PHP

Comment: @SeeJay  glad to help you :):)